# How to make a notification with a sound signal?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, vbscript, task-scheduler

I would like to make a reminder so that a notification with a sound signal appears in a month. In Windows Task Scheduler, you cannot send a message along with a beep (message only). At first I wanted to use such a VBScript and add it to Windows startup:

```
    Const minutes = 44640
Do While MsgBox("Reminder", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Reminder")
    WScript.Sleep(minutes * 60 * 1000)
Loop
```

But this cannot be done. As far as I understand, this is also impossible to do using a VBScript, since the countdown will be constantly reset after the computer is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Use Microsoft To Do

One of the easiest solutions is to use [Microsoft To Do](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NBLGGH5R558). If you set a reminder with To Do, it will pop up a nice toast notification with sound at the specified date and time.

### Option 2: Use a script that can play a sound

You can set a script to run at the designated date and time via **Task Scheduler**. Just be sure to set it to run **only when the user is logged on**. There are several options for playing a sound...

### Reminder.vbs

Here's a VBS script that pops-up a message and plays a sound file. The addition  of `vbSystemModal` ensures your message will be on top of all other windows. You may use `262144` in place of vbSystemModal if you don't want an icon displayed in the dialog caption.

Command: `wscript.exe reminder.vbs`

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Sound.URL = "C:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav"
MsgBox "Reminder", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Reminder"
```

### Reminder.ps1

Here is a PowerShell script that will display a toast notification with sound.

Command:`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass reminder.ps1`

```
function Show-Notification {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]
        $ToastTitle,
        [string]
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $ToastText
    )

    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
    $Template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText02)

    $RawXml = [xml] $Template.GetXml()
    ($RawXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "1"}).AppendChild($RawXml.CreateTextNode($ToastTitle)) > $null
    ($RawXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "2"}).AppendChild($RawXml.CreateTextNode($ToastText)) > $null

    $SerializedXml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $SerializedXml.LoadXml($RawXml.OuterXml)

    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($SerializedXml)
    $Toast.Tag = "Time remaining"
    $Toast.Group = "Time remaining"
    $Toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddMinutes(1)

    $Notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("Time remaining")
    $Notifier.Show($Toast);
}

Show-Notification "Put your reminder messsage here"
```

### Reminder.hta

Here is an HTA script that displays a message and plays an MP3 file:

Command: `mshta.exe reminder.hta`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application
  maximizeButton=no
  minimizeButton=no
  contextmenu=no
  showintaskbar=no
  scroll=no
>
<script language=VBScript>
Window.ResizeTo 600,200
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Put your reminder message here</h2>
<audio src="Test.mp3" autoplay>
</body>
</html>
```